# Observer character data of added nodes with mutation observer

Tags: javascript, nodes, addeventlistener, mutation-observers

Here is my html,

```
<div role="textbox" aria-multiline="true" data-slate-editor="true" data-slate-node="value" contenteditable="true" zindex="-1" style="position: relative; outline: none; overflow-wrap: break-word; min-height: 24px;">
<div data-slate-node="element">

<p> 
<span data-slate-node="text"> 
<span data-slate-leaf="true">

<span data-slate-placeholder="true" contenteditable="false" style="position: absolute; pointer-events: none; width: 100%; max-width: 100%; display: block; opacity: 0.333; user-select: none; text-decoration: none;"> 
What are your thoughts? 
</span> 
<span data-slate-zero-width="n" data-slate-length="0">
 sa qwkq</span> 
</span> 
</span> 
</p>
 </div>
 <div data-slate-node="element"> 
<p> 
<span data-slate-node="text">
<span data-slate-leaf="true">
 </span>
 </span>
 </p> 
</div>
 </div>
```

do NOTE 
it is dynamically added when I press the enter key
as seen here

```
   textBox.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
      if (event.currentTarget.textContent.trim().length > 1) {
        if (!!sendCommentButton.disabled) sendCommentButton.disabled = false;
      } else {
        sendCommentButton.disabled = true;
      }
    
      if (event.key === "Enter") {
        // You can set initial content as needed
        const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        newDiv.setAttribute("data-slate-node", "element");
        newDiv.innerHTML = `
            <p>
             <span data-slate-node="text">
                <span data-slate-leaf="true">
                  <span data-slate-zero-width="n" data-slate-length="0">&#xFEFF;<br>
</span>
                </span>
              </span>
            </p>
          `;
    
        event.preventDefault();
        textBox.appendChild(newDiv);
    })
```

hwever as I type in the first character this

```
<span data-slate-zero-width="n" data-slate-length="0">&#xFEFF;<br></span>
```

should be replaced by this

```
<span data-slate-string=true>w</span>
```

> I assumed here I just entered a character w

as soon as the first character hits , and once the last character is removed from data-slate-string, it should return to the former state
then any other backspace in its former state should remove the whole `<div data-slate-node='element'>{...for the particular span element the event occurs ...} </div>`
I have used mutation observers and event listeners but it seems not working
Your answers is deeply and I will provide any info needed

```
const textBox = document.querySelector('div[role="textbox"]');
```

Elaborated and Cont... from the previous question

```
function subscriber(mutations, observer) {
  mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
    if (mutation.type === "characterData") console.log(mutation.type);
    mutation.addedNodes.forEach((node) => {
      let leafNode = node.querySelector('span[data-slate-leaf="true"]');
      console.log("Added node: " + leafNode);
      observer.disconnect();
      observer.observe(leafNode, { characterData: true });
      //leafNode.addEventListener("keyup", (ev) =>
      ///  console.log(ev.target.innerText)
      // );
    });
  });
}
const textObserver = new MutationObserver(subscriber);
textObsever.observe(parentElementofDivsAdded, {characterData: true, childList: true, subtree: true})
```

I howver intend that when a node is added, I want to know the character data of this dynamic node as I type, that is

```
parentElementofDivsAdded.addEventListener("keydown", ev => if(event is "enter key") add a new div)
```

so I everything works up to the point where I want to observe the leafNode, to see its dynamic character content , thats as I type in the added node that is query selected as seen above and as I backspace , just similar to how "input" event works but this is a span element , I appreciate any responses and I will definitely ensure that I do any updates needed

Comment: It's still not really clear what the problem is and what you want to achieve, but there's one thing I can say: you can't generally expect contenteditable to only perform one kind of mutation as it depends on the internal implementation used by the site, i.e. you'll likely have to process all types of mutations.

Comment: Yea but one challenge I faced is I observed the textbox which is the content editable but at the same time , i have tried to see if I can observe the element node added on enter key press and react to text changes which will replace the children of leaf-node in html as seen with data-slate-string, and when backspace or removal of character should revert to exactly that state when data-string-slate is empty then a further backspace should remove the whole div slate-node=element , this should work for all added nodes .Please help I have work a lot on it , thanks in advance, any code is accepted

Comment: if mutation observer is best, help , if event listener is best help, whatever ingenious ideas, I am 100% appreciative @wOxxOm

Comment: I think if there is a way to observe the <span data-slate-string=true></span> , it will make it easy for me to detect when the character data of it is finished and track any further backspace event  . but data-slate-string is dynamic and textbox is being observed already, @wOxxOm